# Do useSelector() and useDispatch() replace mapStateToProps() and mapDispatchToProps()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React & Redux, and many of the guides I've been using are a couple years old. It seems that Hooks in both  React and Redux are relatively new, and the general recommendations I've seen are to replace class Components in React with functional components and `useState()`.

What I'm unclear on as I go through Redux exercises is if `mapStateToProps()`, `mapDispatchToProps()` and `connect()` are still relevant, or if I can now replace that with the `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` hooks.

Currently, with the `mapStateToProps()` and `mapDispatchToProps()` setup, I have a parent component sending my Redux store state to multiple children, through multiple levels. Whenever I add a new state variable into my store this involves drilling that new state through all these components, made doubly cumbersome by the fact that I'm using Typescript and have to update all my `ownProps` types.

One option would be to `connect()` each child component directly to the store. Could I instead use `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` for each of the children components where I actually use the state variable? What would be the downsides to this?

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'm actually going to transition an app from Redux to React Query this weekend. I suppose it depends on the complexity of your app, but I found myself with a ton of useless global state, odd useEffect code for reacting to various state changes, etc. React Query easily solves all of that.

Comment: FWIW, we actually just released the first alpha version of a new lib called [RTK Query](https://rtk-query-docs.netlify.app), which a Redux-based query library built on top of Redux Toolkit.  We're working on some updates to it now.  Once we're happy with the final API, we'll merge it back into Redux Toolkit.  You might want to check it out as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as per the other answer, the React-Redux hooks API replaces the existing `connect` API, and we specifically recommend using the hooks API as the default:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react
- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api

Part of that is that we recommend using TypeScript with Redux, and the hooks API is a *lot* simpler to use with TS than `connect` is:

- https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-useselector-hook

Answer (score 4):

Yes. With useSelector and useDispatch you can completely eliminate Container  whose purpose was to map state and actions into your child component. You just have to assign state to variable inside of your component and dispatch action to redux, e.g. like in this example:

```
export default function AccountScreen(props) {
   const user = useSelector(state => state.account);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        dispatch(updateProfile(user._id, firstName, lastName, alergies, dob, medicalCondition));
        props.navigation.navigate('HomeTab');
    }
```